# Excel: comma in tab-delimited csv file

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a tab-delimited csv file:

```
"a" "b"
"c,d" "e"
```

Excel renders the second row until comma and the rest of the row is not rendered. I enclose each cell in double-quotes but it doesn't help. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. It might be help the volunteers here if you include information such as your Excel version and the import settings you tried without success.

Comment: Also, what is your `Text qualifier` set to ?

Comment: import from text -> check tabstop -> uncheck comma -> finish

Answer (score 2):

I copied your two demo lines to a text file and opened that in excel 2013:

Setting used:

- Delimited (not fixed width)
- Seperator is space.
- Text qualifier set to `"`

[image: First step]
[image: Text qualifier]

I get a properly imported set of four elements, as shown below:

[image: Excel source file and import results]

---

Some wrapper script like below might work.

(Attempt to add a line to the cvs file with the SEP indicator and then to start it with excel. Might work. Might because I have no experience with batch files and this is created with the help of some googling and some WAGs).

```
echo off
echo Creating a file with sep
echo "SEP= " > %tmp%\Sepfile.txt
copy %tmp%\Sepfile.txt + %1 %tmp\%1
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe" "%tmp\%1"
```

Comment: as my comment -> this is for importing... but the csv will be *auto-seperated* when opening via double click... having an option which can be set to "open all csv with \*\*\* seperator" would be helpfull :/

Comment: There are three ways to auto that: 1) I set it in regional options (via control panel). This will be set for all applications.  2) Add a line to all cvs files with `SEP= ` (but that requires modifying all files or writing a wrapper script. 3) or IIRC excel has an override local settings somewhere. I will need to look that up.

Comment: trying to get nasty... doing it the right way you could change the open-command for csv-files to directly throw the file from command-prompt to excel having excel "think" there is the `sep=` in the first line... while it is possible, i stopped impoving my skills that way to long ago... so i need to give it a goodbye here :(

Comment: It might be possible, but that is also beyond my skills. A workaround by copying the file (which I do not even attempt to cleanup aferwards) is ugly. But possible just within writing skills.  Still, it has a lot of WildAssGuesses in it. I might try it on a windows PC once I get home.

Answer (score 0):

make the first line

```
sep=
```

after the = is a tabstop (you simply cant see here) ^^;

you also can use `sep=;` to change the seperator to `;` (or whatever seperator you want to use)